# 70s/80s children's comic about a green ghost/alien and his young human friend?

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

Can't remember much else. The creature or ghost is green and cute, and the human is (I'm pretty sure) a boy.

It's not My Pet Monster, Slimer from Ghostbusters, Casper in the wrong color, or Doop from Marvel.

Comment: I'm gurssing this is a Western comic, not a Japanese manga?

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark, but perhaps The Great Gazoo (from the Flintstones)?
[image: Gazoo]

Had his own [comic book series](http://www.comicvine.com/great-gazoo/4050-36448/)  from [1973-1977](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Gazoo).